# Event Sourcing without eventual consistency?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

We're about to abandon ES because we need consistent read models for processes, and while trying to figure out how we could save ES we were thinking of a consistent read side. Basically a command would be run by an AR, generating the list of events. Those events would be first saved to the event store, then (through some extra coding) exclusively to the read model (in a transactional way, i.a. all projections for all events from a single command would be wrapped in a transaction). Only after that would the events be published. So basically my code would be like:

```
void ExecuteCommand(Command cmd) {
   // validate and stuff...
   var events = GenerateEvents(cmd);
   PersistAllSync(events);
   ApplyProjectionsSync(events);
   PublishAsync(events)
}
```

Apart from obvious performance problems (kind of distributed transactions, bascially serializing all commands)... why is nobody doing that?

Comment: This may become inconsistent in presence of errors. For example, say `ApplyProjectionsSync` succeeds, but then `PublishAsync` fails. This will create a situation where the read model has the changes, but events are not in the stream.

Comment: You should probably spell out what that means; _needing_ consistent read models is actually pretty unusual.  _Believing_ that you need them to be consistent when you don't is pretty common.

Comment: @Lev can you expleain why you need a consistent view, please? Only knowing why we can find the way of doing this with event sourcing...

Comment: Yes, people are doing that. It is called RDBMS. You know what is bothering me with whole event sourcing? You need to manually solve nontrivial issues that people spent last 50 years to solve. These people are known as database engineers. So how confident you are that you can do that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I can try to answer this anyway.

To get transactional consistency I group produced events (within the same aggregate/transaction scope) and apply them all atomically to my read models. And I also publish events grouped into transactions as well. It works fine for me so it's certainly possible.

To avoid eventual consistency in local read models (so that I can return new and consistent state in the command-response) I also apply events locally within the transaction. As long as you don't have too many read models to update I guess this shouldn't be a problem. You can have this for some read models that need to be non-eventually updated and consistens and handle the rest in the "normal" way if you want.